# Best way to get the count of how many different tables an id showed up in? I have about 25 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database where each table is for a certain location, and I want to see how many unique location tables an id shows up in.

Is there a way that I can get the count of tables an id shows up in without going through and joining all of the tables?

Comment: This is a bad design, exactly because it makes queries like this difficult. You should have a single table where the location ID is a column.

Comment: You can generate the query dynamically in a stored procedure by getting all the table names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`.

Comment: There's no reason to have multiple tables, one per location. Just create a single table with a column `location_id`. Queries will become much easier to write, to test, to debug, and to optimize.

Comment: To answer your second paragraph question - No; the best you can do is as above, use dynamic SQL to build the required query against all your tables - unfortunately this is the cost of a bad design.